# prevent mouse from moving between X screens

Tags: matlab, cursor, screen, mouse, x11

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and have two monitors each assigned to its own screen under X11.  I am wondering if there is a way to prevent the mouse cursor from moving off of Screen 0 and onto Screen 1.  Screen 1 shows images and movies and is controlled with a MATLAB toolbox and Screen 0 displays the GUI and controls, etc, so no need for the mouse to ever go on to Screen 1.  When it does I can't see it given my setup.

Comment: wow, I don't think you'll find a way to do that with a pure Matlab solution. The desktop size and mouse allowed movements are controlled at the OS level ... better ask the question in a more Ubuntu/X11 focused community.

Comment: @Hoki X is not "OS level", it's userspace.